# How do I resolve this error when I try to open a file with vim

Tags: bash, macos, vim, vi

I am on MacOS (Sierra), I am opening an empty new file with the following command

```
vi test_file.txt
```

But then I get this error in the terminal in red color.

> Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
>   E492: Not an editor command: ++nested if &filetype !~# '^git' | call kite#onboarding#call() | endif
>   Press ENTER or type command to continue

It seems to overlay on top of any test if present in an opened file.

Any idea what I should try to correct this?

Comment: You have a bad .vimrc it seems. You may have more luck at [vi.se]

Comment: Where do I find this file in macos? I dont seem to have one

Comment: In your home directory usually. Type `:help startup` in vim.

Comment: I encountered the same issue since yesterday, and my .vimrc only has one line "syntax on". After I use AppZapper to uninstall the Kite application, the issue stills there.

Answer (score 2):

uninstall Kite vim `sudo rm -rf $HOME/.vim/pack/kite/` will solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some kind of error on your vimrc, try loading vim without any setting:

```
vim -u NONE test_file.txt
```

After editing your file you can try to figure out waht the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Start **Terminal** and run the following to open your `vim` startup file with **TextEdit**. i.e. without needing `vim`, so that you can put it right.

```
open -e $HOME/.vimrc
```